# how we run .js extention file through terminal or as a script

Tags: javascript

like we write our C/python codes as script and compile or run using  gcc somthn.c and python somthn.py,what we do in the case of javascript.Is there any way to run javascript program as a script,and run the .js extention.I am new to this language,thats why am asking.Anyone please give me a exact answer

Answer (score 0):

I installed Node.js, then run any javascript like so provided that you are in the folder containing your script in the console:

> node myScript.js

works a treat, and node is awesome.

https://nodejs.org/en/

Also, there are many awesome libraries that you can install with NPM.
Go to nodeschool.io and learn a bunch there.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
Cscript.exe "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\test.js"
```

> Starts with Windows Scripting host

or

```
Wscript.exe "C:\Users\Alice\Desktop\myfirstjs.js"
```

> Starts Windows Version

Have a look at [this answer...](https://superuser.com/questions/488763/how-to-run-js-file-from-a-command-line-on-windows)